# drop down nav background is making two shapes not one

Tags: css

```
    .clearfix:after {
    display:block;
    clear:both;
}

/*----- Menu Outline -----*/
.menu-wrap {
    width: 70%;
    height: 10%;
    position: relative;
    top: 0%;
    left: 20%;
    box-shadow:0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    background:#3e3436;
    border-radius: 10px;

}

.menu {
    width:1000px;
    margin:0px auto;

}

.menu li {
    margin:0px;
    list-style:none;
    font-family:'Ek Mukta';
}

.menu a {
    transition:all linear 0.15s;
    color:#919191;
}

.menu li:hover > a, .menu .current-item > a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#be5b70;
}

.menu .arrow {
    font-size:11px;
    line-height:0%;
}

/*----- Top Level -----*/
.menu > ul > li {
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    font-size:19px;
}

.menu > ul > li > a {
    padding:10px 40px;
    display:inline-block;
    text-shadow:0px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

.menu > ul > li:hover > a, .menu > ul > .current-item > a {
    background:#2e2728;
}

/*----- Bottom Level -----*/
.menu li:hover .sub-menu {
    z-index:1;
    opacity:1;
}

.sub-menu {
    width:160%;
    padding:5px 0px;
    position:absolute;
    top:100%;
    left:0px;
    z-index:-1;
    opacity:0;
    transition:opacity linear 0.15s;
    box-shadow:0px 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    background:#2e2728;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;

}

.sub-menu li {
    display:block;
    font-size:16px;
}



.menu li:hover .sub-menu {
    z-index:1;
    opacity:1;
}

.sub-menu li a:hover, .sub-menu .current-item a {
    background:#3e3436;
}


.clearfix:after {
    display:block;
    clear:both;
}
```

Here is a link to the site so you can see what i'm talking about. it looks like two beveled rectangles instead of one. I'm pretty confident its not html. the site is mainly run off this css stylesheet right now.

http://www.previewmywebsitenow.com/app/browse.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Flgfinancialmgt.com&b=0&f=norefer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 div elements with the `menu-wrap` class remove one and it will be fine.

Comment: yes. eventually noticed that. thank you. also did happen to have duplicate html.